# Monitor change detect CMD call

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

***Project setup***

There is a thread that continuosly checks if there is or not, some kind of change at the monitor setup. Using NVidea functions I can see if there is or not a cable plugged in or out to the vide card. If there is a new one connected ->> call the following code:

```
system("displaySwitch.exe / extend");
```

I also tried to run with admin rights (Opt. 1. starting the program as admin; Opt. 2. with the code shown in following):

```
system("runas /user:<admin-user> \"displaySwitch.exe / extend\"");
```

Furthermore the monitor setup consists of using 2 DVI, 1 HDMI and 1 DP ports. If I test my code, there is one setup (I leave only 1 DP and 1 DVI) when the above mentioned *system* function calls don't change anything. In other cases the code runs well, I see that its executed and the result is also good.

In the case when it does not do any change, if I run it from cmd promt manually I get the wanted result. (Monitors are setuped correctly)

***Question***

Why do I get a different result by calling directly from CMD and calling the same program from the C++ program!?

Comment: OS is Windows 7. But I will try ShelleExecute also. The weired thing is that for some types of connection it works but for others not.

Comment: The big advantage of using native Windows functions (ShellExecute/CreateProcess) is that they set `GetLastError()`

Comment: Tested! But here is an issues! If I have the 4 connections as mentioned above and I just disconnect one DVI -> only HDMI remains as connected other devices remain disconnected although I call the ShellExecute + displaySwitch -> It only sets back if I press Windows + P or use the same command from CMD. Any idea?